# Polarization Operators identity and $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: combinatorics, algebraic-groups, invariant-theory, generalized-polarization-modules

(**This question is also posted in Mathoverflow:**
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/286539/polarization-operators-and-the-action-of-gl-ell-mathbbr-on-mathcalr)

Let $X$ be a matrix of variables $x_{ij}$ of size $\ell\times n$:
\begin{equation*}
X=\left(\begin{array}{cccc} x_{11}&x_{12} &\dots & x_{1n}\\
x_{21}&x_{22} &\dots & x_{2n}\\
\vdots& \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
x_{\ell 1}&x_{\ell 2} &\dots & x_{\ell n}\\\end{array}\right).
\end{equation*}
The ring $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}=\mathbb{R}[X]$ of polynomials in $\ell$ sets of $n$ variables is defined as the $\mathbb{R}$-vector space generated by the monomials:
$$X^{A}=\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{n}x_{ij}^{a_{ij}}$$
The multidegree of a monomial in this ring is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\deg\left(X^{A}\right):=\left(\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{1j},\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{2j},\dots,\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_{\ell j}\right)
\end{equation*}
So an element $f\in\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ have the form
\begin{equation*}
\displaystyle{f(X)=\sum_{A\in\mathbb{N}^{\ell\times n}}f_{A}X^{A}}
\end{equation*}
The **multidegree** of $f$ is given by:
\begin{equation*}
\deg\left(f(X)\right):={\max}_{{\rm grlex}}\left\{\deg\left(X^{A}\right):\ f_{A}\neq 0\right\}.
\end{equation*}
where the maximum is taken w.r.t. the **graded lexicographic order** in $\mathbb{N}^{\ell}$. So the ring $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is $\mathbb{N}^{\ell}$ graded.

Soit $Q$ la matrice diagonale suivante:
\begin{equation*}
Q=\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
q_1&0&\dots&0\\
0&q_2&\dots&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\dots&\vdots\\
0&0&\dots&q_{\ell}\\
\end{array}\right)
\end{equation*}
A polynomial $f(X)\in\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is said to be **homogeneous of multidegree ${\bf d}$** if the following condition holds:
\begin{equation*}
f(QX)={\bf q}^{\bf d}f(X).
\end{equation*}
where ${\bf q}=(q_1,\dots,q_{\ell})$, ${\bf d}=(d_1,\dots,d_{\ell})$ , ${\bf q}^{\bf d}=q_1^{d_1}\dots q_{\ell}^{d_{\ell}}$. It's well known that

> For a matrix of variables $Y=(y_{{ij}})$ of size $\ell\times n$ and $f\in\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ an homogeneous polynomial of multidegree ${\bf d}$, then for every matrix $M$ of size $\ell\times\ell$ we have
>   \begin{equation*}
> f(MX)=\sum_{\big\{K\in\mathbb{N}^{\ell\times\ell}:\ \big\vert{K}\big\vert={\bf d}\big\}}
> \frac{M^{K}}{K!}\,\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{\ell}P_{j,i}^{k_{ij}}
> \big(f(Y)\big),
> \end{equation*}
>   where $$K!:=\displaystyle{\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{\ell}k_{ij}!}$$
>   $$\displaystyle{M^{K}=\prod_{i=1}^{\ell}\prod_{j=1}^{\ell}m_{i,j}^{k_{ij}}}$$
>   and the **polarization operator** $P_{ik}$ is given by
>   $$P_{i,k}:=\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{n}x_{ij}\frac{\partial\ }{\partial y_{kj}}}.$$

The notation $\ \big\vert{K}\big\vert={\bf d}$ represents the set of all squares matrices $K$ of order $\ell$ such that $\displaystyle{\sum_{j=1}^{n}k_{ij}=d_{i}}$, for all $i$ such that $1\leq i\leq\ell$.

> **My question:** Reading Claudio Procesi book I saw that the ring $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is closed under polarization operators $P_{ik}$ if and only if is closed under the action of the general linear group $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$. Using the formula for $f(MX)$ above I can understand why geing closed under the $P_{ik}$ implies that $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$ is closed under the right side action of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$. But, how to find the matrices $M$ to show the reciprocal of this result.

Thank for any hint on this.

Comment: This seems rather similar to your question on MO: [Polarization operators and the action of $GL_{\ell}(\mathbb{R})$ on $\mathcal{R}_{n}^{(\ell)}$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286539).

Comment: Do I have to erase it from one of the sites ?

Comment: To me a reasonable course of action seems to read advice about this on meta. In particular, [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5085/moderator-supported-official-guidelines-for-legitimate-crossposting/5088#5088) - but there are also other discussions on [meta-tag:cross-posting]. After reading the advice, you can decide for yourself what to do. (As I mentioned in a comment on your other question, I think that adding a link to other copies would be a reasonable thing to do.)